# Iterate through concatenated string with paths - prevent globbing

Tags: linux, shell, debian

How to loop/iterate through string

```
exclude_args=''
exclude='/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'
set -- "$exclude"
shift
for path; do
  exclude_args="$exclude_args --exclude '$path'"
done
echo "$exclude_args"
```

## output

```
 --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'
```

How to get an output like this

```
 --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/*' --exclude '/var/test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have it tagged `Linux` and `Shell` I presume you want a POSIX shell solution. You can do the same thing allowing normal word-splitting to take place using `printf` as Heemayl correctly suggests in his answer, but without the arrays. First if your system allows you to employ `set -f` to prevent pathname expansion, use:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f
exclude_args=""
exclude='/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'
printf " --exclude '%s'" $exclude
printf "\n"
```

If you cannot use `set -f` for whatever reason, you will need to wrap each component in single quotes to prevent expansion, you can forcibly do this with `sed`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exclude_args=''
exclude='/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'
exclude="$(echo "$exclude" | sed -e "s/[ ]/' '/g" -e "s/\(^.*$\)/'\1'/")"
printf " --exclude %s" $exclude
printf "\n"
```

**note:** no quoting on `$exclude` as the argument to `printf` is intentional.

If you want to capture that output in the `exclude_args` variable, (and your system provide the `-v` option for `printf`, you can simply use the `printf -v` form, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
exclude_args=''
exclude='/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'
exclude="$(echo "$exclude" | sed -e "s/[ ]/' '/g" -e "s/\(^.*$\)/'\1'/")"
printf -v exclude_args " --exclude %s" $exclude
echo "$exclude_args"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh exargs.sh
 --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/*' --exclude '/var/test'
```

If that's not what your are looking for, them I'm confused, drop a line with any additional info required.

Comment: Your solution doesnt give the expected output.. have just copy/pasted your code and the output is: `sh test.sh
 --exclude '/var/www/bak/site/ini' --exclude '/var/www/bak/site2/db' --exclude '/var/www/bak/site2/ini' --exclude '/var/www/bak/site2/site' --exclude '/var/www/bak/site3/ini'`

Comment: Add `set -f` at the top. (to disable pathname expansion)

Comment: # sh test.sh
test.sh: 2: set: Illegal option -

Comment: What are you running this on? It's tagged 'linux' which if you look under `man bash -- set` gives the details. Let me think about another quoting solution. OK, see the two other solutions posted.

Comment: the first returns: `printf: Illegal option -v` BUT the second works :)

Comment: but.. the input string is `'/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'`

Comment: Hmm. I wrapped each path component in `''` to prevent the expansion since `set -f` gave you trouble. What about wrapping input in double-quotes and adding internal single quotes on each side of the space with `sed` e.g. `exclude="$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/[ ]/' '/g" -e "s/\(^.*$\)/'\1'/")"` with your **input** provided as the first argument to the script. See the updated reformat of `exclude`

Comment: I'm curious what you are running this on that doesn't provide the POSIX `set -f` option. I ask because it is a POSIX option, see [**POSIX Programmers Reference**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06)

Comment: How do I see what I'm running the script under? It just plain sh.. have not installede any third party stuff

Comment: but I use set in my script supplied in my question and it works fine `set -- "$exclude"`

Comment: `echo $SHELL` usually shows the default executable for your shell. Nothing wrong with `set --`, it's just not needed to parse your `exclude` variable. You can use it, but `printf` will do it all for you as well. There are a number of ways to do it. Controlling *pathname expansion* is key. Without `set -f` or insuring that each term with globbing is enclosed in quotes, I would be wary of expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You are following the rather skewed path. Leverage an array and `printf`:

```
exclude=( '/var/www/bak/*/*' '/var/test' )
printf -- '--exclude %s ' "${exclude[@]}"
```

- `exclude=('/var/www/bak/*/*' '/var/test')` puts the required contents as elements of array `exclude`
- `printf -- '--exclude %s ' "${exclude[@]}"` prints the array elements with the string `--exclude` in front

To get a newline at the end, add an `echo`:

```
printf ...; echo
```

**Example:**

```
$ exclude=( '/var/www/bak/*/*' '/var/test' )

$ printf -- '--exclude %s ' "${exclude[@]}"; echo
--exclude /var/www/bak/*/* --exclude /var/test
```

Comment: `exclude` is a function argument.. how would you transform the string `/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test` to `exclude=( '/var/www/bak/*/*' '/var/test' )` ?

Comment: @clarkk Do: `exclude=( $@ )` inside the function, all positional parameters would split by `IFS` and become array elements...

Comment: you dont understand.. its passesd as one concatenated string.. these paths are not the only arguments

Comment: so the variable contains `/var/*/* /var/test /var/hey/*`

Comment: @clarkk You want to pass `/var/*/* /var/test /var/hey/*` as argument to a function, and what you want as output from that function?

Comment: the output is explained in the question.. you got the right output in your answer.. I just need the right way to get there.. from the concatenated string